# What is best way to recover data from database?

Tags: java, mysql

I have a database with table "Customers". I am currently creating a customer application where administrators should be able to create/delete etc customers. so I want to have one safty in case you delete a customers by mistake. My question are, what is the best way to restore a customer if being deleted?

I was thinking of just having an own table for deleted customers but dont know if there are other ways to achive this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use “soft delete”.  That means you don’t really ever delete anything, instead have a flag on each row you can toggle to show a customer is not active. Then you can have a view that shows only non-deleted customers that the code not concerned with undeleting can use.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is to add a `boolean active` column to your Customers table

```
create table Customers (
  firstname varchar(20),
  secondname varchar(20),
  active Boolean default true
);
```

And then when you select your records

```
select * from Customers where active = true;
```

Then, rather than deleting entries from your customers table, you can just set active to false

Answer (score 1):

An approach is to not actually delete the customer and add an additional status column.
In the business layer you will be able to display all users with status != DELETED.

OBS:
If you actually need to delete them from the database, you can make a cron that will scan all customers with status deleted and deletes them after x days.

Answer (score 1):

1. You should be taking database backups.

   Backups are your "first line of defense" - against accidental deletions ... and against anything *else* that could happen (like a hard disk crash, for example.  Or a meteor crash.).
2. Another approach is to assign a [trigger] to any delete (or, for that matter, to "insert" and "update" statements as well).  You can prevent deletion (if you wish), and you'll have a record of who tried to delete.

   Here is an example: http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2011/10/mysql-hacks-preventing-deletion-of.html
3. Finally, the best approach might be to never delete at all: just create a new "status" column.  Set the initial value to "ACTIVE", and "deleted" value to "DELETED".

Answer (score 1):

I agree totally with what @paulsm4 wrote.

I would also add that you could consider using [Hibernate Envers](https://hibernate.org/orm/envers/).

Envers will create new tables that will record the changing state of audited tables.